# Apache2 and /icons path behaving differently

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mono

My site is written in asp.net using mono and apache under ubuntu LTS.

After debugging most of the problems out I still had problems with my icon folder `icons`. It was giving me the wrong or no icon. Then I notice `/blah` gets me my custom 404 page while `/icons` gets me a directory listing.

Why is `/icons/` path hitting a directory instead of using my asp.net code? No other path that I know of (ATM) does that.

Side note: `/images/` also exist in the same directory as my icons folder. `/images/` does not cause a directory listing either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your httpd.conf you have something like

```
Alias /icons /path/to/icon/dir
```

Comment: And... Directory ...Options Indexes

Comment: it was in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf`

Answer (score 11):

Apache2 comes out of the box with an alias mod file enabled at this location:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf
```

and this is the content of that file

```
<IfModule alias_module>
        # Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is
        # Alias fakename realname
        #
        # Note that if you include a trailing / on fakename then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  So "/icons" isn't aliased in this
        # example, only "/icons/".  If the fakename is slash-terminated, then the
        # realname must also be slash terminated, and if the fakename omits the
        # trailing slash, the realname must also omit it.
        #
        # We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If
        # you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.

        Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"

        <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
                Options FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

So you can remove the sym link at

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf
```

to disable the behavior.

Comment: f apache and my 7 year old question. I'm having a fantastic time with nginx

Comment: Yea, I prefer my newer NodeJS servers.  But it doesn't make sense to move legacy apps from Apache to Nginx right now.  Apache works.

Comment: WTF... wondered why my icons result in a 404 with a clean fresh install of Debian and Apache. Never imagined that there is such a nasty default!?!

Comment: 12 years later, bitten by this. lol. wtf.

Comment: I came here to tell you I love you, this gave me a headache

Comment: I can't believe this is enabled by default. Apache, for f**s sake. By the way, I came here because of [this section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/webpack/#extracting-svg-files) of the Bootstrap CSS documentation, where it shows how to extract SVG icons into a folder called `icons` >:(